# Unicode generic currency ¤ translitteration

Tags: unicode, iso, transliteration

I'd like to translitterate some Unicode characters in the most generic way possible, but I'm stuck with the generic currency sign, "¤".
I was thinking of translitterating other currencies to their ISO 4217 3-letter code, so for example:

- € => EUR
- ¥ => JPY
- etc.

There are 2 codes that could correspond to "¤":

- XTS: "Codes specifically reserved for testing purposes"
- XXX: "The codes assigned for transactions where no currency is involved"

However, I don't know which one fits best.

Any idea?

Source: [ISO 4217](https://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/lists/list_one.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found my answer: XTS.

Indeed, in [the french version of the Wikipedia page of ISO 4217](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217), there are more details:

```
XTS : code réservé pour effectuer des essais (aucune transaction contractuelle effective, devise inconvertible, aucune opération de change autorisée, aucun prélèvement de frais de transaction) ;
XXX : code réservé pour des transactions contractuelles effectuées sans devise associée (par exemple transfert d’informations sur les caractéristiques non monétaires d’un compte, d’un contrat ou d’une transaction, taux de change nul, mais prélèvement de frais de transaction associés possible dans une autre devise).
```

which can be translated to:

```
XTS : code reserved for testing purposes (no effective contractual transaction, inconvertible currency, no foreign exchange operation allowed, no direct debit of transaction costs) ;
XXX : code reserved for contractual transactions where no currency is involved (for example information transfer about non monetary caracteristics of an account, a contract or a transaction, zero exchange rate, but possible direct debit of associated transaction costs in another currency).
```

Moreover, [the Wikipedia page about "¤"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)) says that it is "used to denote an unspecified currency", and if the currency is unspecified, the exchange rate is unknown, so you can't convert it.

Since XXX seems to denote a real transaction, but without currency, while XTS seems to denote a fake transaction with a fake currency, I think the latter is closer to "¤" than the former.